# Linq Entity Framework ..Navigation to Link values

Tags: linq, entity-framework

In Entity Frame work I have 2 tables in the database AppType and Application. AppType has a primary key TypeID and TypeName. Application Table has AppID primarykey,AppName,TypeID foreign  key from AppType Table.

I have drop down list which is bound to AppType Type Names..Now I want to return the Application Names on the basis of selected TypeNames of the Drop Downlist. I am using Linq with Entity framework.

Providing code will be much appreciated.

Comment: Providing code will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already loaded all the application types in the dropdown select list (SelectedAppType), this code should work. The basic idea is to query the data using AJAX and change the contents of dropdown for applicatons each time a different  Application type is selected.

In the view:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SelectedAppType").change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var subItems="";
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetApplications","yourController")", {id:val} ,function (data) {
              $.each(data,function(index,item){
                subItems+="<option value='"+item.AppId+"'>"+item.AppName+"</option>"
              });
              $("#SelectApplication").html(subItems);

            });
        });   


    });
</script>
```

Controller Action to get Applications by ApptypeId and return JSON to view.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetApplications(int appTypeId)
    {
        IList<Application> result = db.Applications.Where(a => a.AppTypeId == appTypeId).ToList();

        return Json(result);

    }
```